# Async / Await using babel regenerator-runtime does not work in ie11

Tags: webpack, babeljs, internet-explorer-11, babel-polyfill, babel-preset-env

I have a template app that I want to make work with ie11, for that I'm using webpack + babel.
For some reason I ignore, my JS does not work at all in ie11 even though I did set it as a target in my config. To test it, I use a ie11 on the internet but I don't have access to the stack errors since I'm on MacOS.

What am I missing here?

Source code for more info : https://github.com/VelynnXV/Front-End-Workflow

website : https://nifty-noether-cafbd5.netlify.app/

app.js

```js
import regeneratorRuntime from "regenerator-runtime";

async function app() {

  console.log('App entry point')
  const template = document.getElementById('app')
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(), 2500))
  template.innerHTML = `
  <div class="web-container">
      <div id="">
          Async / awat test
      </div>
  </div>
`
  console.log('App finished')
};
app();
```

webpack.config.json

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: ['core-js/stable', './src/app.js'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'app.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    publicPath: "./src/",
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: true,
    port: 9000,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ // will generate the html file WITH app.js
      // see plugin here : https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: './index.html'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [ // set of rules letting webpack know how to handle .xyz files 
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/, // source: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',

        }
      }
    ],
  },
};
```

babel.config.js

```js
// babel.config.js

module.exports = api => {
    return {
      plugins: [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      ],
      
      presets: [
        [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          {
            useBuiltIns: "entry",
            corejs:3,
            // caller.target will be the same as the target option from webpack
            targets: api.caller(caller => caller && caller.target === "node")
              ? { node: "current" }
              : { chrome: "58", ie: "11" }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "front-end-workflow",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run clean && npm run build && webpack serve",
    "build": "webpack",
    "clean": "rimraf ./dist"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.17",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.17",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.17",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.2",
    "html-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.8",
    "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.23.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.3",
    "core-js": "^3.3.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `webpack` 5 you might have to set the `target` for `es5` to make it work on IE11 as following:

```js
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  // ...
  target: ["web", 'es5'],
}
```

Comment: ooh my god i spent a week searching for a solution and that was it

Comment: How come i did not find this in any documentation?

Comment: i'm not sur this work on latest webpack version : "Error: Unknown option: .target."

Answer (score 1):

Your providing two babel configurations - one embedded in `webpack.config.js` and one in `babel.config.js`. Pretty sure the `webpack.config.js` config will take precedence and clobber the babel config. So just rm the `options` param to `babel-loader` in your webpack config and stick with babel config file.

Comment: Hello, I applied your modifications (updated the code in my post as well), but the problem persists and i dont know why. thanks!

Comment: Well that's at least one problem solved. In Q you just say ~ "JS is not working at all ..." I'm not sure what the persisting problem actually is. It would help if you cut down the example code to the bare minimum you need to test the babel is working / not working for the target. I.e. you entry point should look something like https://pastebin.com/E0Zw2KcX, then bare minwebpak and babel conf too.

Comment: thanks for the help, I modified my app.js and set an `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(), 2500))` before changing the innerHTML of my div. It does not work on ie11. (i updated the code on my post)

Comment: Is there any examples of a  template webpack project using babel that actually works with ie11? with async/awat and scss imports?

Comment: Code in Q is still pretty complex. 1. main.js does not need to be mentioned. 2. Don't use function export for babel config, just export an object. 3. You can probably just strip out the webpack SCSS loaders to focus on async/await which seems to be the issue your havng. You also don't need the nullish and coallescing plugins - presets should handle that.

Comment: I simplified the Question, I'm just not sure about the syntax to use when you say Don't use function export for babel config,